# Is there a way to activate build time tracking in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I am trying to track build times in visual studio for Mac but cannot seem to find the same functionality that the windows version has. Would be thankful for pointers!

Comment: How do you enable this in Visual Studio on Windows? Is there an extension you can install? There is nothing available for Visual Studio for Mac that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an accurate timing tracking for each project, the build time can be seen by clicking on the status bar in the middle on top of vs for Mac. At the end of the build log there is a line that says

```
Time Elapsed 00:01:57.85
```

You can also call msbuild directly on the terminal. By using the switch /filelog you can look at the log on a windows pc with MSBuild Log Viewer: http://msbuildlog.com for more details.